# PHP app under subdomain of Gitlab's nginx

Tags: nginx, php, gitlab

I have set up Gitlab using Omnibus. It has embedded nginx. It works fine on ports 80 and 443. On 8083 I also have installed VestaCP. VestaCP has Softaculous. Using Softaculous I have installed a PHP application under a subdomain. Unfortunately, when I am trying to access this subdomain I am being redirected to Gitlab (by Gitlab's nginx).

I have tried adding:

```
location /scheduler {
        root /home/admin/web/mydomain.tld/public_html/scheduler/;
        index index.php;
}
```

in */opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/nginx.conf* and then running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` as well as `gitlab-ctl restart` but it didn't work.

What do I have to do to view */home/admin/web/mydomain.tld/public_html/scheduler/index.php* when I will try to access *mydomain.tld/scheduler*? Currently, *mydomain.tld/** is mapped by Gitlab.

Comment: I simply wouldn't do that because it can cause you problems down the road, especially when you update gitlab.

Comment: @Broco Does it mean that I shouldn't expose anything else from my server (on default port)?

Comment: Not that, but you get all kinds of weird issues if you employ customizations to the default gitlab setup. You can expect to manually update your gitlab-nginx configuration every time you update gitlab. After half a year it annoyed me so much, my gitlab runs in a vm with its own public IP now, saved me hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

> What do I have to do to view /home/admin/web/mydomain.tld/public_html/scheduler/index.php when I will try to access mydomain.tld/scheduler?

One general error I spotted in your code is the duplicate `scheduler` subdirectory. If your location is `/scheduler/`, the `root` should only be `/home/admin/web/mydomain.tld/public_html/`, as nginx will take the location and prepend it to the root.

See the [nginx docs for root](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more details. Maybe you also want to use `alias` instead.

Comment: I have removed "scheduler" from the line starting with "root" and reconfigured Gitlab. Nothing has changed (still mydomain.tld/scheduler redirects to Gitlab).